# Sending multiple messages to SNS on a single call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a scenario where every time lambda runs, it will send 1000 messages to a SNS topic.
I can loop through the list of messages and call the publish method 1000 times, one message at a time but I was wondering if there is a way to send multiple messages in one call.
In that case I can batch the messages and call publish let say 10 with 100 messages on each execution.

I would really appreciate if someone can help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `SNS` [publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sns/publish.html) you could publish message one by one, AWS does not provide a way to publish message in bulk or batch to SNS.

Below is the possible solution you could try:

You could use [send-message-batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/send-message-batch.html) API and send bulk messages to SQS. That SQS will be subscribed by a SNS. Below is an image to create subscription to SQS:

[image]

Comment: Amazon SNS cannot "subscribe" to an Amazon SQS queue.

Answer (score 3):

SNS has just introduced the PublishBatch API, which you can use to send up to 10 messages to an SNS topic in a single API request. More information on the feature launch can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-sns-supports-publishing-batches-messages-single-api-request/

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve it directly via SNS maybe you can have a SQS queue at the front and back of SNS to post and receive messages as batch.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessageBatch.html